# Find shortest path in online game using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, path-finding

I am developing script, which does some things in online game with TCP sockets. I have only map size, starting X and Y and coordinates where i must go. I need to set X and Y every ms, let's imagine that character's speed is 1 tile/ms. How can i easily do this?

Comment: Search around for "A* algorithm" for some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you can "see" the entire map or not, you'll need to implement either a [pathfinding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding#Algorithms) or [maze solving algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm).